# Merging dataframes by names using R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I want to create a function that merges dataframes whose names contain a defined character string. In the following example, `myfun(A)` would merge the dataframes whose name contains "A", that is, `A1` and `A2`, leaving `B1` out.

```
A1=data.frame(id=paste0("id",1:10),var1=letters[sample(1:26,10)])
A2=data.frame(id=paste0("id",1:10),var2=LETTERS[sample(1:26,10)])
B1=data.frame(id=paste0("id",1:10),var3=letters[sample(1:26,10)])
```

My best try (which does not work):

```
myfun=function(my.pattern){
  dfs=ls(,pattern=paste(my.pattern)) # Getting the list of dataframes whose name contains the pattern
  merged_df=merge(dfs[1],dfs[2],by=id) # Merging those dataframes
  return(merged_df)
}
```

Comment: Try `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='id'), mget(ls(pattern='A\\d+')))`

Comment: @akrun, Spot on! Thanks a lot

Comment: Seems like some type of dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `mget` to get the value of the objects from the `ls` in a `list` and then we can `merge` by using `Reduce`

```
myfun <- function(my.pattern){
 v1 <- ls(pattern=my.pattern, envir=parent.frame())
 Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'id'), mget(v1, envir=parent.frame()))
}

myfun('A\\d+')
# id var1.x var1.y
#1   id1      d      R
#2  id10      c      V
#3   id2      z      E
#4   id3      w      W
#5   id4      l      U
#6   id5      y      X
#7   id6      h      P
#8   id7      n      H
#9   id8      f      O
#10  id9      g      A
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function often, it takes in a directory, and then you give it a criterion it should select .csv files.

```
combine_csv <- function(dir, criterion1 = "subject"){ 
    dir<-list.files(dir, full.names =TRUE)
    data <- data.frame()
    cat_string <- c() # inititalize character vector

    for (i in dir) {
            if (grepl(criterion1, i)) {

                    cat_string <- c(cat_string, i)
            }
    }
    tables <- lapply(cat_string, read.csv, header = TRUE)
    data <- do.call(rbind , tables)
    return(data)      
}
```

It can even be customized to include multiple criteria

```
if (grepl(criterion1, i) & grepl(criterion2, i))
```

Or the way i use it is to look through a parrent folder, and check subfolders if they contain the .csv's im looking for

```
    for (i in 1:length(parent_dir_content)) {
            cur_dir <- parent_dir_content[i]
            if (grepl(criterion1, cur_dir)) {
                    cur_files<-list.files(cur_dir, full.names =TRUE)
                    for (j in 1:length(cur_files)) {
                            cur_file <- cur_files[j]
                            if (grepl(criterion2, cur_file)){
                                    cat_string <- c(cat_string, cur_file)
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```